# Twilio Studio AND Twilio Messaging Service SAME number

Tags: twilio

https://gyazo.com/63cde836b15f181ab0d1cfa6e353d35c

I have two separate API's. One API I'm using the messaging service to bulk send messages to 1k users. Recently I've been experimenting with Twilio Studio and created another API to send a survey flow to customers where they could also reply to the incoming message and its get recorded in my db.

The issue here is, twilio studio wont read the customer's message if I have messaging service. If I remove the phone number from the messenging service, then twilio studio starts reading messages again. Is there anything in the config of messenging service that I can change so that I could have both concurrently?

Comment: As Lizzie mentioned, the problem is that you bound the messaging service to the same number that you want to use in the survey. Wouldn't it make sense to use a separate number for the survey instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds like you have this incorrectly configured such that you need to be using the Messaging Service when you send out the bulk messages as Studio will trigger and create a User based on Messaging Service + User as the To-From pair.

This [tutorial from my former teammate Tilde on Using Twilio Studio and Conversations with SMS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-twilio-studio-conversations-sms) may be helpful.

Let me know if this helps at all!